# After writing any code in onClick, ClickableSpan, it's causing a memory leak

Tags: java, android, kotlin, memory-leaks

```
├─ android.app.assist.AssistStructure$ViewNodeText instance
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 347.6 kB in 6681 objects
│ Library leak match: instance field android.app.assist.
│ AssistStructure$ViewNodeText#mText
│ ↓ AssistStructure$ViewNodeText.mText
│ ~~~~~
├─ android.text.SpannableStringBuilder instance
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 347.5 kB in 6680 objects
│ ↓ SpannableStringBuilder.mSpans
│ ~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 36 B in 1 objects
│ ↓ Object[1]
│ ~~~
├─ cim.exapmle.
│ RegisterActivity$setClickableSpan$clickableSpan$1 instance
│ Leaking: UNKNOWN
│ Retaining 16 B in 1 objects
│ Anonymous subclass of android.text.style.ClickableSpan
│ this$0 instance of cim.exapmle.RegisterActivity
│ with mDestroyed = true
│ ↓ RegisterActivity$setClickableSpan$clickableSpan$1.this$0
│ ~~~~~~
```

---

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    setAgreementStyle(binding.tvAgreements)
}

private fun setAgreementStyle(textView: TextView) {
    viewModel.agreements?.let { agreements ->
        textView.text = textView.context.getString(
            R.string.login_and_registration_agreements,
            agreements[0].text,
            agreements[1].text,
        )

        highlightText(
            textView,
            highlightBoldWord = agreements[0].text,
            highlightBoldWord2 = agreements[1].text,
            highlightColor = ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, R.color.purple),
            highlightColorWord = agreements[0].text,
            highlightColorWord2 = agreements[1].text,
            highlightSizeWord = null,
            highlightSize = 12
        )

        for (i in agreements.indices) {
            val agreement = agreements[i]
            val start = textView.text.indexOf(agreement.text)
            val end = start + agreement.text.length
            setClickableSpan(textView, start, end, agreement)
        }

        textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
}

private fun setClickableSpan(textView: TextView, start: Int, end: Int, agreement: Agreement) {
    val spannableString = SpannableStringBuilder(textView.text)
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
            textPaint.isUnderlineText = false
        }

        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            if ((lastBottomSheetClickedTime + 1500) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                lastBottomSheetClickedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }
    }

    spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```